# Ansible register multiple variables within a single task

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible task and I want to register multiple variables inside it, how do I achieve this? It doesn't seem that a list or a comma separated string would work.

I want to do something like this:

```
- name: my task
  module_name:
    <some more params>
  register: [var1, var2]
```

If I add `register: var1 \n register: var2` then only the second one get's registered.

EDIT:
OK, I think my confusion lied in the bit how variable registration works. So when you do `register: any_var_name`, the newly created variable contains the whole output of the task. Then you can access it any way you want as in the accepted answer.

Comment: What's is the reason for doing this?

Comment: I want to check values of several values in an output of task `my task` in a following task

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Ansible (as of current version 2.4) does not allow to register partial output of the module (or several different parts of it).

You can register only full result and extract parts of it in the tasks to follow.

For example, if you want to get `std_out` and `std_err` of `command` module, you would do two tasks:

```
- command: myscript.sh
  register: cmd_res
- set_fact:
    std_out: "{{ cmd_res.stdout }}"
    std_err: "{{ cmd_res.stderr }}"
```

And **you can't do this in single shot**, like this:

```
- command: myscript.sh
  # this code does not work!
  register:
    std_out: result.stdout
    std_err: result.stderr
```

Comment: According to docs, it's possible: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/1055803c3a812189a1133297f7f5468579283f86/lib/ansible/modules/set_fact.py#L83

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you do it in multiple steps?

```
 - name: my task
   module_name:
     <some more params>
   register: var1

  - set_fact:
       var2: "{{var1}}"
```